# Convert dates like 04-Jan-2016 with numpy to %d%m%Y

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, numpy

my script get some quotes  from a txt file like:

```
4-Jan-16,6.57,7.03,6.55,6.87,45962100
5-Jan-16,6.92,7.00,6.62,6.68,29446700
6-Jan-16,6.53,6.54,6.40,6.40,67507200
7-Jan-16,6.19,6.43,6.08,6.26,57387900
```

and split it into 6 numpy arrays
the first array is for dates but when I try to convert it to day month year like:

```
stockFile = stock+'.txt'
    stockDate, stockOpen, stockHigh, stockLow, stockClose, stockVolume = np.loadtxt(stockFile,delimiter=',',unpack=True, converters={ 0: mdates.strpdate2num('%d%m%Y')})
```

It returns the error:

```
time data '4-Jan-16' does not match format '%d%m%Y'
```

And how can I invert it to Year month days pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the pattern `'%d-%b-%y'`, because `%b` is the short month names format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should adapt your input string format to something like this:

```
%d-%m-%Y
```